# Synchronisation between sound file and animation

Tags: iphone

i have 25 images and a sound file of 2 seconds.

I am ale to play the sound and playing the animation but the synchronization is not getting between sound and the animation ...

Can any one please help me how to synchronization the animation with sound...

There are 25 frames and the sound file duration is 2 seconds...

Can any one please help me how to synchronize the both ......

Answer (score 0):

Whether the animation is manual triggered by means of swiping or it s automatic ?
If it s manual like in the case of swiping you can call the sound file to play whenever the animation is (manual like swiping)done.
Post some of your code. Then we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to [Animation iOS with sound file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13765341/animation-ios-with-sound-file/17127989#17127989) for a step by step on how to play a sound with AVAudioPlayer and then blit a specific image to the screen at exactly the right time.