# Animation iOS with sound file

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, uiviewcontroller

I have some animation which needs to appear on screen at very specific timings, these are stored in SQLite database. What I am planning to do is use nstimer to keep time and pop the animation when the specific time is reached.

Im thinking of using an NSTimer to count for the duration of the sound file and animation then when certain points are reached pop an on screen animation. The problem is the set timing are like this 55.715000 seconds so are very accurate and these need to sync with an audio track that will be played with the animation.

Firstly is this even possible, secondly how can i compare such specific timings the problem i seem to be facing is the code can't run quick enough and the time jumps more than .001 of a second.

I have no knowledge of openGLES or Cocos2d and learning these is not really feasible for the time scales.

Comment: Your user isn't going to notice animation out of sync with audio unless it's more than about 0.25 second.  If you can get things to 0.1 second accuracy you'll be fine.

Comment: The idea is to fire about 4 items per second some repeat items which concerns me that one will run into another and it will end up with one instead of 2. My other concern is older hardware this could lead to bigger lag.

Comment: I recently did something vaguely similar, and what I did is have the animation finish routine stop the sound (and start another, if indicated).  Most people won't notice if a 10th of a second of sound is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of how accurate your timings are, you aren't going to get the device to display more frequently than about 60Hz (16.7 ms per frame). As I see it, you have at least two options here:

1) Use a [`CADisplayLink`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) callback to check the playback progress of the audio and trigger each animation as it becomes timely.

Display link timers are created in a similar way to regular `NSTimers`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(scheduleAnimations:)];
    [self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)scheduleAnimations:(CADisplayLink *)displayLink
{
    // get playback time from player object
    // iterate queue of timings
    //     if the timestamp of a timing is equal to or less than the playback time
    //         create its animation for immediate execution
    //         remove it from the queue
}
```

2) Create a collection of animations, setting their respective `beginTime` properties to the appropriate trigger time (or, if using implicit or block-based animations, use the `delay` parameter).

```
[CATransaction begin];
// iterate collection of timings
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"key"];
    animation.startTime = /* time to trigger animation */
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    [layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: That sounds like a possibility the problem i can see is there is about a hundred animations to do over a 3 minute sound file. So the first option might be best my main concern as above is lag on the older hardware.

Comment: Yeah, definitely go with the former method if you have more than a few animations to perform.

Answer (score 2):

If your visuals need to be exactly in sync with the audio (for example a music app where animations have to appear on the beats) then you need to use the following approach. It works on very old iPhone hardware and there is basically nothing that can go wrong at runtime.

1. Pre-render each "frame" of your visuals so that each one is stored as a full screen image. This could be done on the desktop or you can run the render logic on the phone and then capture the output to a file as pixels.
2. Once each frame is saved as an array of pixels, play the audio via the standard AVAudioPlayer APIs on iOS. This API takes care of the audio playback and reports a time that you will use to determine which video frame to display.
3. Once audio is playing, get the "time" and divide it by your video framerate to determine which image from an array of N images to display. Get the image data and wrap it up in a CGImageRef/UIImage, this will blit the image data to the screen in a optimal way.

If you would like to see working source code for this approach, take a look at [AVSync](http://www.modejong.com/AVAnimator/examples.html#AVSync). This example code shows the implementation that I used in my own app called iPractice in the app store. It is very fast and can run at 30FPS even on the old iPhone 3G.